# Do $h$-cobordism groups arise from a 'Thom-like' spectrum?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, differential-topology, cobordism

Not thinking about $h$-cobordism, one usually defines a *cobordism* between manifolds, realizes it is an equivalence relation, chooses an appropriate class of *structured manifolds* (framed, unoriented, spin, ...), and dreams about the group of cobordism classes of these manifolds.

Thinking about $h$-cobordism, whose definition I learned today, one seems to not think this way. At least, I've glanced through the Wikipedia page and some notes/articles about $h$-cobordism and there is no explicit mention of 'the set of $h$-cobordism classes of $n$-manifolds (possibly with structure)' or its (group) structure.

(Taking after Will Sawin and Connor Malin's comments)

There is not an interesting group of $h$-cobordism classes of manifolds in general (see comments.) But there is, for instance, interesting groups of $h$-cobordism classes of homotopy spheres.

> Is there any interpretation of these groups of a similar spirit (e.g., using spectra) to the relationship between cobordism and Thom spectra?

Comment: The whole point of the group structure in manifold cobordism is that the disjoint union of two manifolds can be cobordant to one manifold (e.g. their connected sum). But in $h$-cobordism, that is impossible, since a space with two components can't be homotopic to a space with one component. So why would one expect there to be a useful group structure?

Comment: @WillSawin There is a particularly famous h-cobordism group of homotopy spheres studied by Kervaire and Milnor...

Comment: @ConnorMalin Sure, but the nicest way of defining that group doesn't use cobordism in any way. It's just diffeomorphism classes of homotopy spheres under the operation of connect-sum.

Comment: @WillSawin Am I misremembering? I thought the elements were h-cobordism classes of homotopy spheres. Of course this turns out to be diffeomorphism classes, but that doesn't take away from the fact they defined them as a type of h-cobordism group.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Sure, I'm just saying the definition in terms of diffeomorphism seems nicer. This is compatible with the fourth paragraph of the question.

Comment: @ConnorMalin and Will Sawin - I've edited my question a good bit after seeing these comments.

Comment: Whitehead groups are parameterized by fundamental groups, not integers. In the $h$-cobordism theorem (and Whitehead's theorem), the Whitehead group is an obstruction to uniqueness. The corresponding obstruction to existence is Siebenmann's end theorem, using Wall's finiteness invariant. These are the cases $n=1,0$ of a spectrum related to $K$-theory whose homotopy groups are called higher Whitehead torsion or (stable) parameterized $h$-cobordism groups. But this introduces a new direction of variation, not weaving together very similar objects like in the Thom construction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This topic has a very different flavor from what is usually meant by cobordism. No, the correspondence between cobordism classes and homotopy classes (of a Thom space or Thom spectrum) has no analogue here; when manifolds, or cobordisms between manifolds, are created by transversality, we don't have much control over their homotopy types.

I would say that the main point of considering h-cobordisms is that surgery theory (in the sense of Wall, Browder, Novikov, ...) is pretty good at answering questions like "How many manifolds, if any, have a given homotopy type?" but where "how many" means up to the equivalence relation of h-cobordism. So, to complete the picture we need to know something about the distinction between this equivalence relation and the one that we originally cared about.

Comment: In response to some comments I have edited my question since they clarified some misunderstanding and led me to be a bit more specific. I think this answer works regardless, though.